# How can I display the link only if I'm not already on taht page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, link-to

I'm using Rails 4.2.7.  I have this link in the header of my application

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_users_path %>
```

How would I not render this link if I'm already on the edit_users_path page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the condition at the end of the erb fragment

```
<%= link_to('Edit', edit_users_path) unless current_page? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

just call

```
<% if current_page?(edit_users_path) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I assume you mean "<% if !current_page?(edit_users_path) %>"